# Any date range in DatePicker for SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Normally we need a range, for example:

```
DatePicker(selection: $birthDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
```

We can select a date for previous date. How can we create a DatePicker which is able to select any date?

There is a method to allow to select a date within a specific range:

```
  var dateClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let min = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -10000, to: Date())!
    let max = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 10000, to: Date())!
    return min...max
  }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just leave the range out:

```
DatePicker("Date of birth", selection: $birthDate, displayedComponents: .date)
```

or:

```
DatePicker(selection: $birthDate, displayedComponents: .date) { Text("Date of birth") }
```